# parameter of incompatible type (weird problem)

Tags: objective-c, protocols

I downloaded Xcode 4 recently and I got this new warning that I didn't have before.
The following code (in FTSocialNetworkingController class):

```
jsonConnection = [[FTJsonConnection alloc] initWithUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] 
                                                  delegate:self];
```

give this warning :

```
FTSocialNetworkingController.m: warning: Semantic Issue: Sending 'FTSocialNetworkingController *' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<FTImageDownloaderDelegate>'
```

I know what the problem means: self should conform to the `FTImageDownloaderDelegate` protocol.
What is weird about that is that the delegate parameter in the `initWithUrl:delegate:` method is of type `id <FTJsonConnectionDelegate>` and the method is declared like this in the FTJsonConnection class (.h)

```
- (id)initWithUrl:(NSURL *)anUrl delegate:(id <FTJsonConnectionDelegate>)delegate;
```

I don't know why it asks for the FTImageDownloaderDelegate since I'm not even using it in the FTSocialNetworkingController class.

I've just got the problem today and I don't know where it comes from.
My other classes which use the `initWithUrl:delegate:` method don't have the problem.

So if someone has any idea of what this is about...

Comment: What code do you want me to post because there is not a lot of code around the call to initWithURL:delegate: method

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with the wrong delegate being reported. Not sure where it comes from.

Comment: Could be a bug in XCode 4. I have the same problem here.

Comment: I'm not alone anymore! I think it is just a parsing/indexing bug. I don't remember if I fixed it or not (but I don't think so). And there was no problem ever during the app execution and Apple approved the app a while ago. But I understand it is annoying to have warnings especially when it's the only one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jsonConnection = [[FTJsonConnection alloc] initWithUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] 
                                              delegate:(id)self];
```

Comment: always best to explain the solution, in addition to give it.